# Django; django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, user, database

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm a beginner and I've been creating a Django project. I'm trying to switch `sqlite3` db to `postgresql`. But when I do `make migrations`, this error occurred.

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host, user, database

I searched about this error. And some people checked `pg_hba.conf` file, but I have no idea where this file is.

Also when I created project before and did the same thing, there's no this error. Why is this error happening this time? What is the cause?

How can I fix this error?

Here is configuration part in `settings.py`

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {

    #elephantsql
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
    'NAME': os.environ.get('DATABASE_NAME', ''),
    'USERS': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER', ''),
    'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PASSWORD', ''),
    'HOST': os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', ''),
    'PORT': os.environ.get('DATABASE_PORT'),
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `settings.py` please. Specifically the part where you configure the database.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Ok, what is the value of `os.environ.get('DATABASE_HOST', ''),`? If it is not `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` (i.e. not running on the same server as the Django installation) you should configure your PostgreSQL server to respond to remote calls.

Comment: do you already make connection listen to all? if you are remote or different server to migrate.

Comment: what does make connection listen mean?
I created db instance on eleplantsql and set the host name of the instance I created as `DATABASE_HOST`

Comment: in `pg_hba.conf` you change ipv4 local connection to `0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: Ive gotten this error before when trying to an incorrectly configured database.
It sounds like your database isn't completely configured.

That file handles access privileges from various sources to the host.

Could you share how you set up your database a bit?

Comment: I mean how I can find the `pg_hba.conf`..
I first created an instance on elephantsql. And then just `export ` environment variables.
Here is the tutorial I've been always following when doing this.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6RbanOhna4&t=236s

Comment: If you are using windows just find in system/program files/postgresql and find there. use `ctrl + f` and it will show up.

Comment: Actually I've used postgresql before on my WSL. But I already uninstalled all files that are related.

Comment: When you are saying WSL do you mean Windows Subsystem for Linux? Wonder if that is the problem. You may want to install postgresql as a native windows application using either the enterprise DB or Bigsql installer https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/

Comment: I installed native application for Windows. I installed PostgreSQL for WSL as well and uninstalled all things.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo to me :
`'USERS': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER', ''),`
should probably be:
`'USER': os.environ.get('DATABASE_USER', ''),`