# Postgresql; Why hasn't postgresql/data folder been removed?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I try to uninstall `Postgresql` completely. But even though most application is already uninstalled, `PostgreSQL/data` folder has not been removed. Is it oaky to delete this folder manually? Or is there a way to delete this folder correctly.
The reason I asked this question is that I cannot use `postgresql` for my Django project.

I posted the question here

[Django; django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, user, database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52378452/django-django-db-utils-operationalerror-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

Basically when I do `python manage.py makemigrations`,

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host, user, database SSL off 
>   no pg_hba.conf entry for host, user, database SSL on

this error happens. I actually have used `postgresql`(elephantsql) for other Django project before and this is the first time I encountered this error.
I don't know why this error happens but I think this error happens after I installed `Postgresql` application on my windows.(I already uninstalled all application a few month ago and folder but still there's an error.) And I wondered if I can delete this folder manually.
I installed `Postgrsql` again so I try to fix this error and tried many things other people answered. (like edited `pg_hba.conf` but never fixed this error. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host)

I've been following this tutorial always

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t6RbanOhna4

I cannot advance anything because of this error.. I'm still looking for people who could help me fix this error.. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The PostgreSQL won't remove the data directory, so if you want to delete the whole PostgreSQL folder but it says **"Folder or File is open in another program"** then you should go to:
**->Task Manager -> 'find the running instance of Postgre' -> End Task**
and then you will be able to delete the whole folder.

Answer (score 0):

The PostgreSQL data directory is not part of the installation, it is created after the installation (often as post-install script) by calling the `initdb` executable.

Deinstalling the software won't remove the data directory.

The main reason for that is that PostgreSQL doesn't know where all the data directories on your system are. You can create more than one in any location you want by calling `initdb` manually.

You will have to remove the data directory by hand.

Comment: Okay I will delete the folder by hand. Could you guess why this error happens this time. I mean I could do as the tutorial does before. I've never seen this error.

Comment: Something is not configured properly. Could be the `listen_addresses` parameter, the `pg_hba.conf` file or the firewall.

Comment: listen addresses was `listen_addresses='*'` by default. And I tried answers https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host refers but never fixed the error.
I think I was successful in configuring db when I didn't install PostgreSQL application.

Comment: Open a different question for that, but I'll warrant that you will find the answer if you search the thousands of questions with that error message.